# Почему не получается установить Hyper-V под Xamarin forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin

У меня не отображается Hyper-V в компонентах Windows, скорее всего из-за того, что у меня всего 4 гб оперативной памяти. Есть ли какие-то способы установить этот компонент, чтобы можно было спокойно работать над приложением в Visual Studio? (Эмулятор запускается очень долго)
Так же постоянно выходят эта ошибка:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Достаточно почитать [документацию](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/reference/hyper-v-requirements) и понять что именно у вас не так. Даже есть специальная утилита проверки (`Systeminfo.exe`), которая говорит почему у вас не работает Hyper-V. Если коротко, то у вас должна быть система Windows Pro и выше (не Home), в биосе должна быть включена виртуализация и она должна поддерживаться процессором. Ну и RAM должно быть не меньше 4гб.

Comment: Ещё система x64 нужна. 4 гига оперативы - мало для виртуалок, расширяйте. Какая Windows? VTx в биосе включено?

Comment: В общем с эмулятором у меня куча проблем, хотел узнать, как запускать приложение на физическом устройстве, а то я все настройки пересмотрел, только на IOS нашёл возможно и то подписку оплатить, а на андроиде вообще не понимаю как это сделать